# How to return indices of values between two numbers in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to return the indices of all the values in a python numpy array that are between two values.  Here is my code:

`inEllipseIndFar  = np.argwhere(excessPathLen * 2 < ePL < excessPathLen * 3)`

But it returns an error:

```
inEllipseIndFar  = np.argwhere((excessPathLen * 2 < ePL < excessPathLen * 3).all())
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use 
a.any() or a.all()
```

I'd like to know if there is a way of doing this without iterating through the array.  Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since `> < =` return masked arrays, you can multiply them together to get the effect you are looking for (essentially the logical AND):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = 2*np.arange(10)
array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])

>>> idx = (A>2)*(A<8)
>>> np.where(idx)
array([2, 3])
```

Answer (score 14):

You can combine multiple boolean expressions by using parentheses and the correct operation:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = 2*np.arange(10)

In [3]: np.where((A > 2) & (A < 8))
Out[3]: (array([2, 3]),)
```

You can also set the result of `np.where` to a variable to extract the values:

```
In [4]: idx = np.where((A > 2) & (A < 8))

In [5]: A[idx]
Out[5]: array([4, 6])
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any difference between multiplication and logical conjunction for `True/False` arrays?

Comment: @Hooked - Not really, but I find the compound logical statements to be more readable

Comment: Old comments, but for future readers: I ran timing on both (logical and multiplication) and the difference appears negligible.